# Angular5 form array validation for dynamically created fields

Tags: angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

I am using angular5 in that I am using form array to dynamically generating the fields. Initially I want to load form array as 0 files. If I am clicking plus button I want to add two fields. With validation.

If from array is empty i.e now fields are created I have to submit the button without this dynamic fields.

If fields are created I have to set validation without entering information in fields i won't enable submit button.

If I am setting validators.required in form array I can't able to submit without entering in first two fields

I need a solution for this one guys.

Comment: post your source code

Comment: Or stackblitz ex?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using template driven approach, the place where you are looping through your data to generate dynamic controls, create an index variable like `*ngFor=" val in collection; let i=index"` and then use that i to make each control unique by appending i with the name of the control like `<input type="text" name="txtId-{{i}} #txtId="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="someId" />`

Now if you try to use txtId.valid inside the loop it will be unique for every row.